# Clear connection pooling in devart?

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, connection-pooling, devart

I have a Windows service application that connects to database every minutes. Somethimes i get this error:

> ORA-20110: ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called

Solution is close and reconnect database in plsql but i want to do this in application side.

So i need to disable all connection poolings and try to reconnect database.
How can i do this using devart ?

> This is my connection

```
this.ConnectMode = OracleConnectMode.Default;
this.Direct = true;
this.Close();
this.Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db_hostname"];
this.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db_port"]);
if (db_connection_type == "SID")
   this.Sid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db_sid"];
else
   this.ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db_sid"];
this.UserId = db_username;
this.Password = db_password;
this.Open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found clearPool of oracleconnection ownclass

```
// C#
// Sample demonstrating the use of ClearPool API in OracleConnection class

using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

class ClearPoolSample
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Running ClearPool sample..." );
    // Set the connection string
    string strConn = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle;" +
                     "Min pool size=5;";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(strConn);

    // Open the connection
    conn.Open();

    // Clears the connection pool associated with connection 'conn'
    OracleConnection.ClearPool (conn);

    // This connection will be placed back into the pool
    conn.Close ();

    // Open the connection again to create additional connections in the pool
    conn.Open();

    // Create a new connection object
    OracleConnection connNew = new OracleConnection(strConn);

    // Clears the pool associated with Connection 'connNew'
    // Since the same connection string is set for both the connections,
    // connNew and conn, they will be part of the same connection pool.
    // We need not do an Open() on the connection object before calling
    // ClearPool
    OracleConnection.ClearPool (connNew);

    // cleanup
    conn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
  }
}
```